# Help me write a regex that validates a number of any size that is between two special characters?

Tags: regex

So that means "$1$" will pass as well as "$50000000000000$" or "$12345678$" length of number doesn't matter but it must be only digits and must start and end with a '$'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
\$\d+\$
```

And if you don’t want to allow leading zeros:

```
\$[1-9]\d*\$
```

Comment: I suggest reading http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528126/ ... utterly, utterly boring, but after plowing through it no regex should be a problem for you.

Comment: favorite learn source is http://www.regular-expressions.info/ And for writing regular expression try http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/